# jquery - dynamically change variable name

Tags: jquery, variables, testing

I've built some purely jQuery code which sends data to GA for when a site user visits a page, scrolls an element we are testing into view on their screen and when the element is clicked.

All that works fine, the code is built to just let the testing team simply enter the id/class of the selector element they are testing as a variable value:

```
var selectorElement = "#element";
```

The problem is I want this tracking code to be reusable so they can copy it into each test and just update the value of the variable. However this reusable code could need to be fired two or more times on the same page if there's more than one element being tested in different places.

If that's the case then it obviously can only store one value in that `selectorElement` variable so only sends the data for one stored element/test not for all tests on that page.

I've racked my brain and failed to figure out how I can make a previously set variable name become unique for each test without the test team having to manually remember what names have been used over live tests and change the name themselves.

We do also store a test ID like `var testID = 00001` for each test which is originally used as part of the data sent to GA.

**Theoretically in my head it seems the ideal solution would be if we could update the `selectorElement`'s name to include the `testID` giving us
`selectorElement00001 = '#element2'` and say `selectorElement00023 = '#element4'`, so if test 00001 & test 00023 were running on the same page they have unique names per test.**

At this point I haven't figured out if you can do that and I'm at a bit of a road block. I need help on what's the best way to allow reusable code to work with it's self seperatly.

Here's a shortened example of the code:

```js
// Test 1 - say was running on the site header so is running on every page

var selectorElement = "element2";
var testID = "00001"

var visibility = testID + ' - test not found';

  //Check if selectorElement is scrolled into view after a 500ms delay after scrolling
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
      if (visibility == testID + ' - test not found') {
        if ($(element).offset().top + $(element).height() - $(element).height()/1 <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() && $(element).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop()) {
          visibility = testID + ' - test in view';
          GAtracking(); // Triggers the data to send to GA with seperate code
        }
      }
    }, 500));
  });
  
  
// Test 2 - say was put live seperatly 3 days later but runs on a page that has the header 
// so test 1 is already running on the same page

var selectorElement = "element4";
var testID = "00023"

var visibility = testID + ' - test not found';

  //Check if selectorElement is scrolled into view after a 500ms delay after scrolling
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
      if (visibility == testID + ' - test not found') {
        if ($(element).offset().top + $(element).height() - $(element).height()/1 <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() && $(element).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop()) {
          visibility = testID + ' - test in view';
          GAtracking(); // Triggers the data to send to GA with seperate code
        }
      }
    }, 500));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div id="element1"></div>
  <div id="element2"></div>
  <div id="element3"></div>
  <div id="element4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use an Object? Something like `let selectorElement = { 'testID': '00001', 'selector': '#element01' }`

Comment: @jonas Thanks for the reply, looking at it, it looks like that is changing the variable value to include the testID and not the variable name. However this does give me an idea I might be able to try